# Stored Procedure Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ListFirmJobFilter]
    (@Status as nvarchar(10),
     @CityID as nvarchar(10),
     @DataStart as date,
     @DataEnd as date,
     @FirmID as nvarchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE 1=1'

    IF @Status IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql += ' AND Status = '+@Status+''
    END

    IF @CityID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql += ' AND CityID = '+@CityID+''
    END

    IF @FirmID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql += ' AND FirmID = '+@FirmID+' '
    END

    IF @DataStart IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql += ' AND (InsertedDate >= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataStart)
        SET @Sql += ' AND InsertedDate <= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataEnd)
        SET @Sql += ')'
    END 

    PRINT(@Sql)
    EXEC(@Sql)
END
```

The command completed successfully.

But when I execute that stored procedure with that parameter

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_ListFirmJobFilter]
                        @Status = NULL,
                        @CityID = null,
                        @DataStart = N'2016-06-26',
                        @DataEnd = N'2016-06-28',
                        @FirmID = 4

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

I get an error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

I look for executed SQL command (Print SQL string). This is executed command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND FirmID = 4  
  AND (InsertedDate >= 2016-06-26 AND InsertedDate <= 2016-06-28)
```

When I execute that it give same error. I changed it to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND FirmID = 4  
  AND (InsertedDate >= '2016-06-26' AND InsertedDate <= '2016-06-28')
```

this worked.

What should I do? `InsertedDate` type is date

Comment: First things first, your procedure is wide open to sql injection. You should never directly execute values received like this. Here is a much better way to handle this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ Also, you really should consider dropping the sp_ prefix (or even better removing prefixes entirely). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap dates in single quotes

```
SET @Sql += ' AND (InsertedDate >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataStart) +''''
SET @Sql += ' AND InsertedDate <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataEnd) +''''
SET @Sql += ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Squirrel, and you noticed it yourself as well, dates have to be enclosed in single quotes.

Personally I like to use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) for this:

```
SET @Sql += ' AND InsertedDate <= ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataEnd), '''')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enclosed your date string in single quote

```
SET @Sql += ' AND (InsertedDate >= ==' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DataStart) + ''''
```